# Karma test failing because of line break?

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine

Been running into a slight situation over the past few hours. I'm attempting to learn Angular 2 and in that pursuit I decided I would create a base skeleton I could build my ng2 apps on top off of. Which finally gets me to my question. I've got my skeleton relatively close to completion but I'm running into an error on my first Jasmine test. From what I can tell it looks like it might be coming from a line break in the div though I'm not %100 sure. I've done some front end development but not too must testing (stupidly) so this is really my first time through. As Angular2 is still not officially released I'm currently using a [plugin](https://github.com/ludohenin/gulp-inline-ng2-template) to insert my templates and sass inline into my ng2 components. From what I can tell this is at the root of the issues. I'm using the `expect(<ng2-element>)toHaveText(...)` structure in the test and this is the current situation:

ng2-element=

```
<p>{{ message }}</p>
```

Test passes.
ng2-element=

```
<p>{{ message }}</p>
```

Test fails

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)
My skeleton [repo](https://github.com/wootencl/Angular2_Foundation_Skeleton)

Per request the code to the failing test:

```
import {Component, provide} from '@angular/core';
import {RouteSegment} from '@angular/router';
import {
  async,
  beforeEach,
  beforeEachProviders,
  describe,
  expect,
  inject,
  it,
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {TestComponentBuilder} from '@angular/compiler/testing';

import {Greeter} from '../shared/index';
import {Hello} from './hello.component';

describe('Hello', () => {
  beforeEachProviders(() => [Greeter]);

  it('renders greeting', async(inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb) => {
    tcb.createAsync(Hello)
      .then((fixture) => {
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement).toHaveText('Hello, Angular2!');
      });
  })));
});
```

Comment: Please provide the code for the failing test.

Comment: Hopefully that helps. Also can be found in the repo for better context: https://github.com/wootencl/Angular2_Foundation_Skeleton/blob/master/app/client-app/%2Bhello/hello.component.spec.js

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/testing/NgMatchers-interface.html#!#toHaveText-anchor), `toHaveText` has the following docs:

> Expect the element to have exactly the given text.

So you will need to be wary of the white space.

It seems like there should be `toContainText` that does a partial match, but until something exists, you could role your own.

In addition, I believe you could also do the following (**warning: untested**):

```
expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.getText()).toContain('Hello, Angular2!');
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. And yeah I noticed that as well when reading the docs so that's what I was thinking. Docs are still lacking quite a lot so I figured I'd hit the SO community. Sadly your suggested fix didn't seem to remedy the situation. Wouldn't be too big a deal but I think this is going to cause issues with my inline templates. For now I'm going to keep the question open and keep researching a possible solution. Thanks for trying to help though!